# Xcode ios react app is blocking only into the simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, typescript, xcode

I have an ios app created in react, when I run in console ionic serve everything is ok, when I run the app into simulator the app is blocking on Axios request.

```
const sendGetRequest = () => {

  return axios({
    url: "https://example.com/wp-json/survey/v1/listOfQuestions",
    method: 'get'
    
  }).then(response => {
    var  answerQuestionsFirstTimeCounting = [];
    for (let index = 1; index <= response.data.length; index++) {
      if(response.data[index] != undefined) {
        var categoryName =response.data[index].category.toLowerCase();
        //categoryName = categoryName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        var search = ' ';
        var replaceWith = '_';

        categoryName = categoryName.split(search).join(replaceWith);
        if(!questionsCategories.includes(categoryName)) {
          questionsCategories.push(categoryName);
        }
      }
      answerQuestionsFirstTimeCounting[index] = 0; 
    }
    
    nrQuestions = response.data.length;
  
    return response.data;
  })
};
```

I was not able to see some log details about this error. The same code is working on the app android.

Someone more experienced in Xcode can help me to tell me, where I can make debug, to see where is the problem?

Update:

I have used proxyman tool to trace request and I have this error:

[image]

The cross origin is ok I have set on server to allo requests from everywere

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The ssl certificate is ok is green
The same API on another server is working, but o this server is not.
I do not have any idea where is the problem, why the request is rejected only into the ios simulator and in real devices.

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated